# Using filter and sample in a grouped dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to get two IDs randomly sampled from a predefined set of IDs.
However, Using `sample` with `dplyr::filter` on grouped dataframe returns unexpected results "different sample size", e.g if I do `sample(x,2)` sometimes I get 2 sometimes I get a number not equal to 2.

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
5L, 5L, 6L, 6L), Sub = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "f", 
"g"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-14L))

samp.vec <- c(1,2,3,4,5)

library(dplyr)
set.seed(123)
#Return Different sample size, Not working
df %>% group_by(ID)%>%filter(ID %in% sample(samp.vec,2)) %>% count(ID)
df %>% group_by(ID)%>%filter(ID %in% sample(samp.vec,2)) %>% count(ID)

set.seed(123)
#Return one sample size, Working
df %>% group_by(ID)%>% ungroup() %>% filter(ID %in% sample(samp.vec,2)) %>% count(ID)
df %>% group_by(ID)%>% ungroup() %>% filter(ID %in% sample(samp.vec,2)) %>% count(ID)
```

One solution is to use `ungroup()` before `filter`. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: What are you trying to do or get?

Comment: If you are sampling from **ALL** your IDs, then why group it? It does not make sense to me. How can you tell group with `ID = 1` to filter when `ID %in% c(2, 3)`??

Comment: @Sotos, my R code looks like `df %>% group_by(ID) %>% #some calcautions #># filter()`. Secondly I'm sure  all `samp.vec` in IDs, so this `ID %in% sample(samp.vec,2)` always valid.

Comment: @NelsonGon, given a longitudinal df "grouped df". I'm trying to sample 2 IDs from a specific set of IDs `samp.vec` then filter these 2 IDs.

Comment: @A.Suliman, but you have to ungroup because If you leave it grouped, then how are you telling group with ID=1 to filter the ID if the ID is `c(2, 3)`. It does not make sense. Do you get what I am saying?

Comment: @Sotos, Sorry maybe I'm missing something here, but why `df %>% group_by(ID)%>%filter(ID %in% c(2,3)) %>% count(ID)` works as intended but not `sample(samp.vec,2)`, which they look similar in concept at least.

Comment: I added an answer. Please let me know If it's clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are grouping, you are doing the operation for each group. So you don't just have one pair of IDs, like the fixed **ID %in% c(2, 3)**. To make this more clear, let's omit `filter` and lets see the results of `sample(samp.vec, 2)`,

```
df %>% 
 group_by(ID) %>% 
 mutate(v1 =  toString(sample(samp.vec, 2)))

# A tibble: 14 x 3
# Groups:   ID [6]
#      ID Sub   v1   
#   <int> <fct> <chr>
# 1     1 a     2, 3 
# 2     1 a     2, 3 
# 3     1 a     2, 3 
# 4     2 b     1, 4 
# 5     2 b     1, 4 
# 6     3 c     3, 1 
# 7     3 c     3, 1 
# 8     4 d     4, 5 
# 9     4 d     4, 5 
#10     4 d     4, 5 
#11     5 f     4, 2 
#12     5 f     4, 2 
#13     6 g     2, 4 
#14     6 g     2, 4
```

So it will filter the 2 IDs from each group. Thus, sometimes you will have 2, sometimes 3 and sometimes all of them.

Comment: Nice shoot. Just one last thing, in your example we will get one group `ID=4` as the filter in that group will be `ID %in% c(4,5)` for example. correct?

Comment: Actually two groups `ID=3` and `ID=4`